# Can't install email module in Python 3.8

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.8 and pip 19.3.1 on Windows 10 and when I try to `pip install email` I get an error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8nsypvg1\\email\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8nsypvg1\\email\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nsypvg1\email\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nsypvg1\email\
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
        import email.parser
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nsypvg1\email\email\parser.py", line 10, in <module>
        from cStringIO import StringIO
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output
```

How do I get this module installed?

Comment: The [`email`](https://pypi.org/project/email/) package that was last released on April 25, 2007? I don't think that will work with Python 3 and your error message confirms it. `StringIO` and `cStringIO` were removed in Python 3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `email` module was distributed for pythons 2.3 and 2.4. Starting with 2.5, it was included in the standard python distribution. You're looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html

Answer (score 0):

Module 'email' is deprecated and no longer being updated. It was last updated on Jul 19, 2011. Latest version of python at that time was Python 2.7

So, it doesn't support Python 3.8. What you can do is install it in Python 2.7

Use the following command to install version 6.0.0 in Python 2.7

```
pip install email==6.0.0a1
```

Comment: It does not make much sense to write an answer from which the OP would infer Python 2 should be used at this point in time (even though you are not saying that - it could be read as a recomendation) - moreover, the "email" module is built-in Python's standard install from Python 2.5 .

Comment: Yes, but when they released version 6.0.0a1 they incorporated python 2.7 support in it according to their webpage. You are right, I did not intend to recommend using python 2.7. It was just to provide a solution and leave it to the user to decide if they want to use it or not.